# How can I globally handle exceptions from all Handlers in Yesod?

Tags: exception, haskell, error-handling, yesod

I have some shared logic in the `defaultLayout` which can randomly fail and raise an exception, and I'd like to handle that in a single place, no matter what handler is currently being executed.

Is there a place where any request-related exception could be handled, and possibly still respond back to the user? (a redirect or an error page or something else)

**edit**: If at all possible I want to be able to distinguish different exceptions with this, and choose to only handle some and ignore others.

Comment: I haven't used it before, but the [`errorHandler`](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/yesod-typeclass#yesod-typeclass_custom_error_pages) function of the Yesod typeclass sounds appropriate, with the [`defaultErrorHandler`](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/df304d6393a419b308f3f9cde6eb791e6b4a5415/yesod-core/Yesod/Core/Class/Yesod.hs#L475) providing an example.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you can do this by writing custom `Middleware` and chaining it into your instantiation of `yesodMiddleware`.